# StackOverflowException at StreamReader constructor

Tags: c#, .net, streamreader, stack-overflow

I have a problem with this code; it caused StackOverflowException. The error occurred in line  `StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path)`.

Anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? Thank you.

```
public string[,] parseCSV(string path)
{
    List<string[]> parsedData = new List<string[]>();
    try
    {
        using (StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string line;
            string[] row;
            baris = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
            row = readFile.ReadLine().Split(',');
            col = row.Length;
            store = new string[baris, col];
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;

            foreach (string kolom in row)
            {
                store[i, j] = kolom;
                j++;
            }
            i=1;

            while ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                row = line.Split(',');
                j = 0;
                foreach (string kolom in row)
                {
                    store[i, j] = kolom;
                    j++;
                }
                i++;
                parsedData.Add(row);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }
    return store;        
}
```

Comment: What `path` does cause exception?

Comment: When the error occurs, show the call stack window in the IDE and tell us what it looks like -- what function called parseCSV and about how many times?  What is the value in the "path" variable?  Is StreamReader the .NET framework class or did you create your own SteramReader?

Comment: the StreamReader constructor that you are using doesn't ever throw a StackOverflowException. Can you post a stack trace?

Comment: Surely you are getting an OutOfMemoryException, not a stack overflow?

Comment: You know you are reading it all twice, right? And keeping it all in memory. Iterator blocks would be good here. Well, actually I'd just use the Fast CSV Reader from codeproject - why reinvent this?

Comment: Also, you know this won't handle CSV with things like quoted fields (with commas or newlines in), or the infamous semi-colon switch?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately stackoverflow doesn't present the call chain.

Check this guy's callers and callers of his callers all the way up.

This guy can't throw stackoverflow by himself.